# Override bean in project added from different project

Tags: java, spring

I have a project A where project B is defined as a dependency. Project B has a bean defined in xml that reads some properties. I have no access to modify project B but need to use this bean in Project A, Is there a way I can use this bean but this bean should read the new properties not the one being read now.

Comment: Adapter or decorator pattern work?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the bean with your new class and have the required properties overrided in your new class.

for eg. following bean is in Project B:

```
<bean id="customer" class="com.napster.Customer">
    <property name="country" value="India" />
</bean>
```

In your project A extend that bean so you will have all the behaviour exposed by that bean along with you can override certain properties.

```
<bean id="retailCustomer" class="com.retail.Customer" parent="customer">
    <property name="country" value="United States" />
</bean>
```

The inheritance should work as long as the beans are loaded in same applicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation in my project, configuration class (in project A) below works as expected:

```
@Configuration
public class NewConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public InterfaceType overrideBean() {
        return new InterfaceTypeImpl();
    }
}
```

The point is to make new bean definition as primary.